# Programmatically share a dropbox link in .net without having user login to Dropbox

Tags: .net, dropbox

I have to programmatically share a dropbox link.
I upload programmatically files to my dropbox folder and need to get the url string of the shared link of my uploaded file.
the process should be- uploading a file to dropbox, **get a shared link for this document** and then I will do something with this link.
I read a lot of topics online and on Stackoverflow, but all I found was with redirecting the user to the dropbox login page, this doesn't fit my case because my users don't have a dropbox account.

i did write my code using the dropnet library.

any help will be very much appreciate.

this is my code:

```
Public Sub ConnectToDropbox()

    '1''''

    Dim _client As New DropNetClient("11111111111111", "222222222222222222")

    Dim login As Models.UserLogin = _client.GetToken()

    _client.UserLogin = login

    _client.UseSandbox = True

    '2

    _client.GetTokenAsync(AddressOf GetToken_success, AddressOf share_failed)

    '3

    Dim url = _client.BuildAuthorizeUrl()

    Response.Redirect(url)

    '4

    _client.GetAccessTokenAsync(AddressOf GetAccessToken, AddressOf share_failed)

    '5

    _client.GetShareAsync("/AttachToEmail/flowers.txt", AddressOf share_success, AddressOf share_failed)

End Sub
```

but can't get it to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DropNet` library. It comes with a way to log into dropbox, and upload a file, and you can write your code in C# .NET.

Uploading the file after you are logged in works like that:

```
var uploaded = _client.UploadFile("/", "test.txt", content);
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. i did the upload like this, my problem is with getting the shared link from dropbox....

Comment: After you have done the upload, you can try to call the GetMetaData to fetch contents from the folder. You know the name of the file that you have uploaded, you can use it to find the file on dropbox, can't you?

Comment: why should I use the GetMetaDat function if what i need is to simply share a link? isn't the GetShareAsync() function better for that? would you be able to write me a code snippet? i do know the name of the uploaded document.

Comment: There's a basic sample snippet under the "Share:" section in the documentation for DropNet: http://dkdevelopment.net/what-im-doing/dropnet/